# How to get a base64 representation of a selected image in Word for iPad

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am having a problem with getting the selected image on Word iPad within the Addin I am developing. I am using the following code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

        // Getting the selected range
        var range = context.document.getSelection();

        // Getting the image from the selected range
        var picture = range.inlinePictures.getFirstOrNullObject();
        context.load(picture);

        // Loading the image properties so we can access it later
        return context.sync().then(function () {                
            var picbase64 = picture.getBase64ImageSrc();
            return context.sync().then(function () {                    
                console.log("Base64 string is " + picbase64.value);                    
            }); 

        });
})
```

This code works perfectly in Word for Windows, Word Online and Word for Mac, but it doesn't work with Word for iPad. I get the following error:

> Base64 string is undefined

Having investigating further, I've found out that apparently Word for iPad interprets the selected image in a different way (not as `InlinePicture`). So, the question is how can I get a base64 representation of a selected image in Word for iPad?

One note - the image I am trying to access is inserted by Word. When I insert image (`InlinePicture`) programmatically, I can access it without any problems.

Comment: According to the docs, the `inlinePictures` property of the [Range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) object was added in API Requirement Set [1.2](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets), which is supported by Office for iPad 1.18 or later. For what version of Office 2016 for iPad are you observing this issue?

Comment: @KimBrandl, I have Word 2.5 (170904)

Comment: In that case, this sounds like a bug with the API. I don't see any issues with your code; it works fine for me on Windows desktop and should work across all platforms.  
The product team uses the [OfficeDev/office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js) GitHub repository to track/manage issues related to the Office.js APIs. I'd suggest that you report this problem by [logging an issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) there, and include a link to this Stack Overflow post, so that this post can be updated when the issue is resolved.  troubleshooting process.

Comment: @KimBrandl, thanks for your response. I've created a new issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/56